# GNOME 3.2 crashing

Tags: 11.10, kernel, ati, gnome

On an Oneiric amd64 (i.e., 64-bit) system, GNOME 3.2 is flickering and crashing. I installed ATI Driver 11.10 and GNOME ran much better. I then compiled kernel 3.1 which caused Firefox and Chrome to crash. I [purged kernel 3.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81900/how-do-i-remove-kernel-3-1-that-i-added-via-a-ppa/81915#81915) and Firefox and Chrome are fine with kernels 3.0.013 and 3.0.0.12.

However, GNOME 3.2 is flickering more frequently and will now crash (the menu is gone and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> will not work. Only recourse is to to do a hard shutdown and reboot. It wasn't crashing at all before kernel 3.1 was compiled and installed. The flickering is frequent, the crashing is new. I had a flicker issue once in a while before I installed kernel 3.1, but not this frequently.

Any thoughts on how to reduce the flickering and crashing?

Comment: Can you edit your post to describe the specific behavior that you're calling crashing? If this is actual crashing, then this is a bug and should be reported as one by enabling [Apport crash reporting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport), reading the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) carefully, and then reporting the bug by producing the crash, submitting crash data to Launchpad when prompted to do so by Apport, and filling out a bug report with details of the problem. (Then edit your question to include a link to the bug.)

Comment: Let me know if this is ok

Comment: If the menu is disappearing while you are using the machine (rather than just always being missing) then this may well be a crash; I recommend enabling Apport and attempting to report it as one. In addition to helping Ubuntu improve, reporting this as a bug will furnish a significant volume of technical information that may make it possible for someone here (or on Launchpad) to provide advice for fixing the problem.

Comment: Are you using Unity or GNOME Shell? (it could be either with GNOME 3.2).

Comment: Gnome Shell (Gnome 3.2).  It really was flickering much less (and not crashing) before my grand idea of installing Kernel 3.1.

Comment: Update: Crashing has stopped.  I installed Cairo-Dock.  I stay away from themes and flickering is at a minimum by staying away from the "Activities" option on the menu.  Is this a ATI  driver issue, a Kernel issue or a Gnome-shell issue?  I am looking forward to the next update to the ATI drivers to see if the flickering issue is respolved.

Answer (score 2):

This might be [Bug #889706](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/889706), have a look at the description and if you think its a good fit mark the bug as affecting you too.